# Find the Limit: $\lim_{x\to2^{+}}e^{3/2(2-x)}$

Tags: calculus, limits, exponential-function

$$\lim_{x\to2^{+}}e^{3/2(2-x)}$$

> **Properties of the Natural Exponential Function:**
>
> The exponential function $f(x)=e^x$ is an increasing continuous
>   function with domain $\mathbb R$ and range $(0, \infty)$. Thus $e^x>0$ for all
>   $x$. Also
>
> $\lim_{x\to-\infty}e^x$=0 and the $\lim_{x\to\infty}$ $e^x=\infty $
>
> So the $x$-axis is a horizontal asymptote of $f(x)= e^x$.

How do I utilize this definition to solve this problem?

Comment: What is $\lim_{x \to 2^+} 3/(2(2-x))$?

Comment: how must we read $3/2(2-x)$? don't you use $\LaTeX$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $$\lim_{x \to 2^{+}} \frac{3}{2(2-x)} = -\infty$$ then $$\lim_{x \to 2^{+}}\exp\left(\frac{3}{2(2-x)}\right) = \exp\left( \lim_{x \to 2^+} \frac{3}{2(2-x)}\right) = 0$$

Comment: well explained.